# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined at HTMLSpanElement.menuBtn.onclick

Tags: javascript

Why isn't it working?

```
const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menu-icon span");
menuBtn.onclick = ()=>{ items.classlist.add("active");
```

**Error:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined at HTMLSpanElement.menuBtn.onclick

Comment: And where is `items` coming from? Also you are missing a closing `}`, may be a typo?

Comment: Ciao, for sure `items.classlist` is undefined. Maybe you could show us more code to understand why is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a typo to me. Please replace `classlist` with `classList`.

```
rest of code ...
const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menu-icon span");
menuBtn.onclick = ()=> { items.classList.add("active"); ... rest of code
```

This property of `element.classList` is defined in `camelCase`. So you can't expect to make a call of it with all lowercase.

Comment: If it looks like a typo then `comment` why answer ?

Answer (score 2):

`classlist` should be `classList`

give away is in the type error.

Answer (score 0):

```
menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
   menuBtn.classList.add('active')
})
```

### Try this maybe this will fix if not then post more code and also where the items came from you used in your code